# Paginador PHP: al dar clic en siguiente página, no aparecen los resultados

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

He programado un buscador en PHP, ahora bien: estoy necesitando que ese buscador me haga una paginado de 12 resultados, sin embargo esto ya lo he logrado; el problema que tengo radica en que cuando doy clic en los botones generados para poder avanzar a cualquier página, ya no me devuelve nada, aparece nuevamente la interfaz del buscador pero sin ningún resultado, es como si se perdiera la referencia, a pesar de que paso el parámetro por método GET en la url. Acá dejo un fragmento de mi código:

```
<?php
$TAMANO_PAGINA = 12;
$pagina = 1;
if (isset($_GET["pagina"]))
{
    $pagina = $_GET["pagina"];
}
$offset = ($pagina - 1) * $TAMANO_PAGINA;
//                                    $pagina = $_GET["pagina"];
//                                    if (!$pagina) {
//                                        $inicio = 0;
//                                        $pagina=1;
//                                    }
//                                    else {
//                                        $inicio = ($pagina - 1) * $TAMANO_PAGINA;
//                                    }
if (isset($_POST['enviar']))
{
    $js = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['js']);
    //echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$js')</script>";
    $trozos = explode(" ", $js);
    //echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$trozos[0] $trozos[1]')</script>"; // Devuelve trozo2 con mermelada
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `jsonBuscador` WHERE `claves` LIKE '%$trozos[0]%' AND `claves` LIKE '%$trozos[1]%' LIMIT $TAMANO_PAGINA OFFSET $offset";
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `jsonBuscador` WHERE `claves` LIKE '%$trozos[0]%' AND `claves` LIKE '%$trozos[1]%'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());
    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2) or die(mysqli_error());
    $num_total_registros = mysqli_num_rows($result2);
    //calculo el total de páginas
    $total_paginas = ceil($num_total_registros / $TAMANO_PAGINA);
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<p class='dark-color fw-600' style='text-transform: uppercase;font-size: 12px;'>Resultados Encontrados: </p>" . $num_total_registros . "<br>";
    echo "<p class='dark-color fw-600' style='text-transform: uppercase;font-size: 12px;'>Mostrando la página </p>" . $pagina . " <p class='dark-color fw-600' style='text-transform: uppercase;font-size: 12px;'>de</p> " . $total_paginas . "<p>";
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)
    {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('No encontramos nada, vuelve a intentarlo')</script>";
    }
    $counter = 3;
    $rep = 4;
    echo "<ul class='products'>"; //primera
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $counter++;
        if ($counter === $rep)
        {
            echo "</ul><ul class='products'>";
            $counter = 0;
        }

        echo "<li class='product col-md-3 col-sm-4'><div class='product-thumb-wrap'><div class='product-thumb'><a href='product.php?tacker=$row[id]'><img src='$row[imagen]' alt=''></a><a href='product.php?tacker=$row[id]' class='product-add-cart'><span class='pull-left'>Ver Más</span><i class='pull-right fa fa-shopping-cart'></i></a></div></div><div class='product-info'><a><h3 class='dark-color fw-600'>$row[title]</h3></a><div class='product-cate'><a>Código:</a> <a>$row[codigo]</a></div></div></li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>"; //última
    
}
else
{
}
?><div class="paginate mt-3 mb-6">
    <div class="paginate_links">
<?php
    if ($total_paginas > 1)
    {
        for ($i = 1;$i <= $total_paginas;$i++)
        {
            if ($i == $pagina)
            //si muestro el índice de la página actual, no coloco enlace
            echo "<a class='page-numbers' id='paginaBusca' href='' style='color: #000 ;border: 1px solid #ff1a00'>$pagina</a>";
            else
            //si el índice no corresponde con la página mostrada actualmente, coloco el enlace para ir a esa página
            //"<a class='page-numbers' href='searchTest.php?pagina=" . $i . "&criterio=" . $trozos[0] . "'>" . $i . "</a>"
            //echo "<a href='searchTest.php?pagina=" . $i . "&criterio=" . $trozos[0] . "'>" . $i . "</a> ";
            echo "<a class='page-numbers' id='paginaBusca' href='searchTest.php?pagina=$i'>$i</a>";
        }
    }
?>
    </div>
```

Agradecería que me ayudaran, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que al cambiar de página ya no accedes a:

```
if(isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
```

porque esos datos ya no existen.
Puedes cambiar el formulario a GET o bien pasar la variable js entre las páginas:

```
//Deberías cambiar el if para que la comprobación fuera saber si tienes el parámetro js
if(isset($_POST['js']) || isset($_GET['js']) {
...
//Dentro de ese if debería estar el páginador, que pasa de página en página 
//el parámetro js
echo "<a class='page-numbers' id='paginaBusca' href='searchTest.php?pagina=$i&js=$js'>$i</a>";
```

Pero mi recomendación es que un formulario de búsqueda siempre sea de tipo get, ya que si el usuario vuelve atrás nunca le saldrá el mensaje para reenviar el formulario.

Te edito esta respuesta poniendo el código completo:

```
<?php   
    $TAMANO_PAGINA = 12;
    $pagina = 1;
    if (isset($_GET["pagina"])) {
        $pagina = $_GET["pagina"];
    }
    $offset = ($pagina - 1) * $TAMANO_PAGINA;
    
    //En vez de comprobar si se ha enviado $_POST['enviar']
    //Comprobamos la recepción de js, si no existe le damos el valor de null
    $js = (isset($_POST['js'])?$_POST['js']:(isset($_GET['js']))?$_GET['js']:null;
    
    //Comprobamos que js existe
    if($js != null)) {
        //Creo una nueva variable con la variable js filtrada
        $jsEscape = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$js);
        $trozos = explode(" ",$jsEscape);
        
        //Haces la consulta suponiendo que trozos tiene al menos 2 elementos
        //Lo ideal sería que, o bien hicieras una comprobación tipo
        //$trozos.length == 2
        // o bien usaras explode para si te envían más de dos palabras
 
        $sql="SELECT * FROM `jsonBuscador` WHERE `claves` LIKE '%$trozos[0]%' AND `claves` LIKE '%$trozos[1]%' LIMIT $TAMANO_PAGINA OFFSET $offset";
        //No deberías hacer otra consulta sin el limit
        //Busca sobre SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
        $sql2="SELECT * FROM `jsonBuscador` WHERE `claves` LIKE '%$trozos[0]%' AND `claves` LIKE '%$trozos[1]%'";

        $result= mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());
        $result2= mysqli_query($conn,$sql2) or die(mysqli_error());

        $num_total_registros = mysqli_num_rows($result2);
        //calculo el total de páginas
                                    
        $total_paginas = ceil($num_total_registros / $TAMANO_PAGINA);
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<p class='dark-color fw-600' style='text-transform: uppercase;font-size: 12px;'>Resultados Encontrados: </p>" . $num_total_registros . "<br>";
        echo "<p class='dark-color fw-600' style='text-transform: uppercase;font-size: 12px;'>Mostrando la página </p>" . $pagina . " <p class='dark-color fw-600' style='text-transform: uppercase;font-size: 12px;'>de</p> " . $total_paginas . "<p>";
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('No encontramos nada, vuelve a intentarlo')</script>";
        }
        $counter = 3; 
        $rep = 4;
        echo "<ul class='products'>"; //primera
                                    
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $counter++; 
            if ($counter === $rep) { 
                echo "</ul><ul class='products'>"; $counter= 0; 
            }
                                        
            echo "<li class='product col-md-3 col-sm-4'><div class='product-thumb-wrap'><div class='product-thumb'><a href='product.php?tacker=$row[id]'><img src='$row[imagen]' alt=''></a><a href='product.php?tacker=$row[id]' class='product-add-cart'><span class='pull-left'>Ver Más</span><i class='pull-right fa fa-shopping-cart'></i></a></div></div><div class='product-info'><a><h3 class='dark-color fw-600'>$row[title]</h3></a><div class='product-cate'><a>Código:</a> <a>$row[codigo]</a></div></div></li>";
      }
      echo "</ul>"; //última
               
      //En vez de cerrar el if, lo comento para mostrar solo el paginador si hay resultados
      //}else{}
      ?><div class="paginate mt-3 mb-6">
         <div class="paginate_links">
          <?php
           if ($total_paginas > 1){
            for ($i=1; $i <= $total_paginas; $i++){
               if ($i == $pagina)
               //si muestro el índice de la página actual, no coloco enlace
                   echo "<a class='page-numbers' id='paginaBusca' href='' style='color: #000 ;border: 1px solid #ff1a00'>$pagina</a>";
               else
               //si el índice no corresponde con la página mostrada actualmente, coloco el enlace para ir a esa página

               //Además de la página, le paso el parámetro js
               echo "<a class='page-numbers' id='paginaBusca' href='searchTest.php?pagina=$i&js=$js'>$i</a>";
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ?>
                                 </div>
```

Comment: Puedes explicarme exactamente adonde debo colocar el código, soy inexperto, he intentado realizar esto y ahora me devuelve todos los resultados de la base de datos, creando mas de 200 paginas, pero persiste el problema de que al dar clic a cualquier otra pagina ya no devuelve mas resultados.

Comment: puedes ayudarme un poco mas @Marc N

Comment: @user3033258, lo que te está diciendo es que cambies el método del formulario a GET y, en el código que pusiste en la pregunta, cambia todos los `$_POST` por `$_GET` y con eso ya va a funcionar.

Comment: Te he editado la respuesta anterior poniendo tu código, pero lo que dice @Triby y lo que te he dicho antes es mejor, usar $_GET en vez de $_POST para enviar el formulario. Un saludo.

Comment: Agradezco la colaboración de todos, he logrado realizar con éxito el pagiador, un saludo.